# Getting return values from function PHP

Tags: php, function

How can I echo the value returned from a function, called within another function in PHP.

For example, if I have function like this:

```
function doSomething($var) {

   $var2 = "someVariable";

   doSomethingElse($var2);

}

function doSomethingElse($var2) {
   // do anotherSomething 
   if($anotherSomething) {
    echo "the function ran";
    return true;
   }
   else {
     echo "there was an error";
     return false;
   }

}
```

I want to echo the echo from the second function inside the first. The reason is because the second function can produce a string when it fails that the first cannot.

So how would I output the returned value from the second function?

Comment: You will get `Notice of undefined variable` for `$anotherSomething`. Where it is declared?

Comment: `echo doSeomthingElse($var2)`?

Answer (score 2):

Create an array containing values that you would like to return and then return that array.

```
function doSomethingElse($var2) {
   // do anotherSomething 
   if($anotherSomething) {
    $response['message'] = "the function ran";
    $response['success'] = TRUE;
   }
   else {
     $response['message'] = "there was an error";
     $response['success'] = FALSE;
   }
    return $response;
}
```

In your other function

```
$result = doSomethingElse($var2); 
echo $result['message'];`
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution actually, let me give it a go. Thanks Dan.